# Scrollbar in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Css is like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,::-moz-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 6px;    /* for vertical scrollbars */
    height: 8px;    /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track,::-moz-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius:4px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

but it works only in chrome ..in other browser it display default scrollbar and second doubt is it start appears in ipad after I scrolldown..how to display vertical scroll if it has max text on hover of the textarea?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/wSctq/4/)

Comment: Please set up a fiddle AND rephrase your question so it makes sense.

Comment: @Rvervuurt please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseout and mouseover events to hide or show the scroll bar using css.

Comment: will try that..and what about css..its working only for chrome not in other browser..do u have any idea?

Comment: I think it will work for other browsers. In the fiddle that you provided scroll bar is appearing in all browsers.

Comment: scrollbar is appearing but css is not applied on other browser..I want scrollbar in all browser like it appears in chrome

Answer (score 0):

For a cross browser solution you should use javascript/jquery. There are many successful scrollbar plugins that you can use

Comment: I dont have to use plugins for this..do u have any example or css in js/jquery for a cross browser solution?

Comment: There's no equivalent for ::-webkit-scrollbar in firefox. So you can't use something like that in firefox.

you can search for custom scrollbars in google. I use 

https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar